# Testing methods returning promise using jasmine

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I am using jasmine & karma to test my angular app. I have a service as follows

```
app.service('demo1', function( $http ){
    this.send = function(){
        return $http({
            url: 'someurl'        
        });
    }
});
```

The response is mocked using `ngMockE2E`.

My jasmine spec is as follows:

```
describe('Testing asynchronus', function(){
    var demoService;
    beforeEach(function(){
        module('app');
        inject(function( demo1 ){
            demoService = demo1
        });
    });

    it('Should be able to test promise', function(){            
        demoService.send().then(function( data ){
            expect(data.status).toBe(true);
        });
    });    
});
```

Now the problem is, the `expect` is not executing. the test being passed every time, no matter what the value of `data.status` is. I need help on how to test these kinds of scenarios? Thanks in advance.

**Real code:**

```
describe("Testing MetaService", function(){

    var _entityMeta_, metaService, scope;

    beforeEach(function(){
        console.log( '---------------------- Starting Meta Service fetchEntityMeta Test ---------------------------' );
        module(APP_MODULE_NAME);

        inject(function(_entityMeta_, _metaService_, $rootScope){
            metaService = _metaService_;
            entityMeta = _entityMeta_;
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
        });
    });

    afterEach(function(){
        console.log( '---------------------- Ending Meta Service fetchEntityMeta Test ---------------------------' );
    });


    // Giving mock data from entityMeta.person as input
    it("Should have a valid structure", function($rootScope){ 

        console.log( '////////////////////////////////////////////' );
        metaService.fetchEntityMeta('person').then(function( data ){
            console.log( data );
            expect(data.type).toBe('object');
            expect(data.properties.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
            expect(data.definitions.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);            
        });        

    });

});
```

I am getting following error:

```
Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified
 by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
```

Comment: ngMockE2E is for end-to-end tests, not for unit tests run with karma. You need to tell the ngMock $httpBackend what to do. Read the documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend

Comment: My main concern is how to test if the method returns a promise. I have tried using $q besides ngMock. It seems that if the function returns a promise the expect block inside the 'then' callback wont get executed.

Comment: You need to call $scope.$apply() (or $rootScope.$apply()) in order for the promise callbacks to be called once you resolve the promise.

Comment: My promise is resolved inside service method. It looks like if the service is mocked & resolved inside the describe block of the spec file, then this $scope.$apply() works for testing it, but in my case, it's not working. I need this to be applicable for real api response, for validating the response of api

Comment: We can't find a bug in code you don't show. Post REAL code, tell us what you expect it to do and what it does instead.

Comment: I have added my real code at the bottom. My expectation is i should be able to test my data structure inside the 'then' callback. But it looks like, that block is not validating the data. Infact, the console.log is also not giving any output. How can i test the response here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80348/discussion-between-yeasin-hossain-and-jb-nizet).

Comment: Once again: you need to tell the ngMock's $httpBackend what to expect and what to answer. Read the documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend

Answer (score 1):

try to add

```
beforeEach(module('app'));
```

under the describe

Comment: Oops I missed that while writing my question. By the way, it's not issue. The issue is when ever a method returns promise, how should i test it? Cause the way i've done it, it's not working.

Comment: usually in unit test the api calls are mocked and not tested cz the code should not depend on api url response @YeasinHossain

Comment: So what you are saying is, in unit test, i can skip writing tests for methods that is dependent on an api call like the send method of  demo1 service, right? My thought was, when my web services are going to be ready & my requests will interact with real api, i can run this test to validate the data structure of my api.

Comment: It is better to do end to end test, use protractor to test angular code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Jasmine 2, the argument to the callback passed to `it` is supposed to be a `done` function called when the test finished. (The test runner will time out if it is never called.)

(See [the official doc here](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support), or [one of many blog posts](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/webdev/uidevelopment/javascript/testing-asynchronous-javascript-w-jasmine/).)

I don't really understand why you pass `$rootScope` in this case, but the error message looks like a complain because the `done` function (which happens to be named `$rootScope` here) has not be called.

This might work :

```
// Giving mock data from entityMeta.person as input
it("Should have a valid structure", function(done){ 

    console.log( '////////////////////////////////////////////' );
    metaService.fetchEntityMeta('person').then(function( data ){
        console.log( data );
        expect(data.type).toBe('object');
        expect(data.properties.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
        expect(data.definitions.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);            
        done();
    }, function (e) {
        // The promise was not resolved, this is most likely an
        // implementation error. Let's fail the test !
        throw new Error(e);
    });        

});
```

If the `then` part is never called, the `done` function will not either, an you'll get the timeout error you're seeing right now.

Comment: Getting the same error. I have increased the jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL to 10000 as per the doc of jasmine. But still not working. Looks like the then part is not being called. Just can't understand why?

Comment: If the problem is that the `then` part is not called, then it's most likely an issue in the code of metaService itself - which is pretty much impossible for anyone but you to debug, since we don't have the code... The general trail to follow would be to make sure "fetchEntityMeta' actually returns a Promise, and that this Promise *really* gets resolved at some point. You might want to add a handler in the `then` part for the error case, maybe you'll get some interesting info. Good luck !